# I can't login to Keycloak with Node

Tags: node.js, keycloak

I want to login to Keycloak with Node. My Keycloak instance runs on a container in a virtual machine. I am using the following code:

```
const axios = require('axios');

function loginToKeycloak(username, password, clientId, realmName) {
    const keycloakUrl = 'https://<ip of my virtual machine>:8443/auth/realms/';
    const tokenEndpoint = `${keycloakUrl}${realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;

    const data = {
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: clientId,
        username,
        password,
    };

    axios.post(tokenEndpoint, new URLSearchParams(data), {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        httpsAgent: new (require('https').Agent)({ rejectUnauthorized: false }), // Ignore self-signed certificate
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('Login successful');
            console.log('Access Token:', response.data.access_token);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Login failed:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        });
}

loginToKeycloak('myUser', 'myPassword!', 'myClient', 'myRealm');
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
'RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: https://<ip of my virtual machine>:8443/auth/realms/realm1/protocol/openid-connect/token'
```

If I type

```
https://<ip of my virtual machine>:8443/
```

in the searchbar of my browser I can view Keyclock's home page. So apparently the address is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the substring "auth", that must be removed.
Therefore this line:

```
const keycloakUrl = 'https://<ip of my virtual machine>:8443/auth/realms/';
```

must be replaced with

```
const keycloakUrl = 'https://<ip of my virtual machine>:8443/realms/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this code will works

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const querystring = require('querystring');

const loginToKeycloak = async (username, password, clientId, realmName) => {
    const keycloakUrl = 'http://localhost:8443/auth/realms/';
    const tokenEndpoint = `${keycloakUrl}${realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;

    const data = querystring.stringify({
        client_id: clientId,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        grant_type: "password"
    });
    axios.post(tokenEndpoint, new URLSearchParams(data), {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        httpsAgent: new (require('https').Agent)({ rejectUnauthorized: false }), // Ignore self-signed certificate
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('Login successful');
            console.log('Access Token:', response.data.access_token);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Login failed:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        });
}

loginToKeycloak('user1', '1234', 'myClient', 'realm1');
```

##### Docker compose

Save as `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy # it will be replace latest or 18.0.0 when to move minikube
      # image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: postgres
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
        # KC_FEATURES:
        #   scripts
      ports:
        - 8443:8080 # Expose to user with localhost:8443
      restart: always
      depends_on:
        - postgres

volumes:
  postgres_data:  # Keycloack volume
      driver: local
```

Run it

```
docker compose up
```

Credential

```
master user: admin
master password: admin
```

##### Create realm and client

```
realm: realm1
client: myClient
```

[image]

##### Create user

```
user name: user1
user password : 1234
```

[image]

##### Get Token URL

```
http://localhost:8443/auth/realms/realm1/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

[image]

[image]

##### Get Token by Postman

[image]

##### Run demo code

```
node login.js
```

[image]